# Entity Framework with Postgres results in "database is being accessed by other users"

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6

I have a Winforms .NET C# application in VS 2017, using Entity Framework 6, Postgres as the database, and `EntityFramework6.Npgsql` as the provider.

Here is my `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="myapp.Properties.Settings.mydbConnectionString" 
             connectionString="Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=testdbpass;Database=testdb;Pooling=false;" 
            providerName="Npgsql" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory 
            type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Npgsql" publicKeyToken="5d8b90d52f46fda7" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.0" newVersion="4.0.5.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

... and here is my code:

```
   class NpgSqlConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public NpgSqlConfiguration()
        {
            var name = "Npgsql";
            SetProviderFactory(providerInvariantName: name, providerFactory: NpgsqlFactory.Instance);
            SetProviderServices(providerInvariantName: name, provider: NpgsqlServices.Instance);
            SetDefaultConnectionFactory(connectionFactory: new NpgsqlConnectionFactory());
        }
    }
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(NpgSqlConfiguration))]
    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestContext() : base("myapp.Properties.Settings.mydbConnectionString")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new ERPInitializer());
        }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class ERPInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<TestContext>
    //public class ERPInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ERPContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(TestContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }


    public static class DBController
    {
        public static TestContext ErpContext = new TestContext();
        public static void PopulateBaseData()
        {
            try
            {
                using (var ctx = new TestContext())
                {
                    if (true)
                    {
                        ctx.Users.Add(new User() { UserName = "testuser", Name = "Test", Password = "testpasswd" });
                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

When I am in development mode and I repeatedly run the application, after a few runs, I keep getting exceptions when trying to add the new record to the database. The exception says:

> {"55006: database \"mydb\" is being accessed by other users"}

... and as the exception detail:

> Detail = "There is 1 other session using the database."

Any ideas why I am having these connection problems?

Comment: have you the same problem if you change the initializer from `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` to something not involving a DDL command ?

Comment: What is the static ErpContext used for? My guess is that the DropCreateDatabaseAlways effectively wants the Database set to SingleUser mode. If another connection is open when this happens (new instance started before another instance has fully terminated) then the application would fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the root cause of the problem is the connection that is maintained by VS2017 when you add a data source via "Project -> Add New Data Source" menu. When we add this data source to VS2017, and then run our application, we get the "There is 1 other session using the database" error. However, when we remove the data source from VS2017, we never see this error.